# creacion de un store procedure en oracle y consumir la data en visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2022

Estoy intentado crear un store procedure en oracle el cual tiene que cargar toda la data de la tabla para yo poder consumirla en visual studio,

tengo el siguiente problema

1. este es el store procedure que yo realice para poder consumir esa data

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CONSULTAR_DATOS AS

```
  CURSOR c_emp_cursor IS SELECT id, descripcion, precio FROM productos;
  
  v_id productos.id%TYPE;
  v_descripcion productos.descripcion%TYPE;
  v_precio productos.precio%TYPE;
  
  BEGIN
  OPEN c_emp_cursor;   --abre el cursor
  LOOP
        FETCH c_emp_cursor INTO v_id, v_descripcion, v_precio;   --asigna los valores a las variables.
        EXIT WHEN c_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;

        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_id ||'  '|| v_descripcion ||'  '|| v_precio);  
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_emp_cursor;       --cierra el cursor.
```

END SP_CONSULTAR_DATOS;
/

al ejecutarlo dice que el procedimiento ha sido compilado con exito,

2. en visual realice el siguiente codigo con el cual estoy intentado consumir la data
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al yo intentar consumir el store procedure, me sale lo siguiente:

[image]

el store procedure si se esta consumiendo bien, mas no esta cargando la data del curso

alguna ayuda sobre el porque se genera asi?

Comment: Debuguea MostrarProductos() y antes de retornar, revisa si lista está lleno de datos. Además puedes intentar encerrar todo eso en un try catch para ver alguna posible exepción.

Comment: @javdromero al intentar pasar todo al try catch me sale el siguiente mensaje "no todas las rutas de acceso devuelven un valor"

Comment: En este caso, el `try-catch` debe de estar encerrando sólo el primer `using`.

Comment: @javdromero te cuento, con el try catch, pude descartar que el store procedure este mal, lo que doy cuenta es que no esta cargando la data del cursor... como podria llamarla en visual studio?